# Backbone Marionette Possible to Add Arguments to all Module Definitions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, module, arguments, marionette

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to pass more than the standard:

module, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _

argument defintion to all module declairations. I do not want to have to add more arguments than the name and function to the app.module call because that will only pass those variables to the modules that have them there. If any one knows how to do this, i would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just define an extra function that you use like:

```
function moduleWrapper(func) {
  var extraArg1 = something, extraArg2 = somethingelse;
  return function() { 
    //Take the arguments obj and convert it to an array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    //splice the extra arguments into the array
    args.splice(5, 0, extraArg1, extraArg2);
    //then call the function passed to the wrapper
    return func.apply(this,args);
  };

}
```

Then you can pass a function with the arguments

```
function example(MyModule, MyApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _, extraArg1, extraArg2){}
```

like this

```
MyApp.module("MyModule",moduleWrapper(example));
```

The wrapper will just call your original function with the arguments you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass extra arguments like this (from the Marionette documentation):

```
MyApp.module("MyModule", function(MyModule, MyApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _, Lib1, Lib2,     LibEtc){

  // Lib1 === LibraryNumber1;
  // Lib2 === LibraryNumber2;
  // LibEtc === LibraryNumberEtc;

}, LibraryNumber1, LibraryNumber2, LibraryNumberEtc);
```

http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.3.0/marionette.module.html#additional-arguments

Comment: i specifically asked to not do this. thanks for trying though